# How to show that two compound poisson random variables are independent?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, independence

I have $X_1$ and $X_2$ two independent random variable. For $j=1,2$, define the classical compound poisson random variables:
$$Y_j = \sum_{i=1}^N X_{ij}, \quad N \sim Poisson(1), \quad X_{ij} \sim X_j$$
where $(X_{ij})_{i\geq 1}$ are identically distributed random variables that are mutually independent and also independent of $N$.

So I want to show that $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are independent.

This result seems to be true, since $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent, but the sum of poisson to $N$ in each one is making it difficult for me.

**Update**

According one comment bellow, I have to assume that  for $j=1,2$
$$Y_j = \sum_{i=1}^{N_j} X_{ij}, \quad N_j \sim Poisson(1), \quad X_{ij} \sim X_j$$
and $N_1$ independet $N_2$.

Answer (score 1):

They are not necessarily independent. Consider the case $X_1=1=X_2$ and remember that a constant is independent of any other variable. Then $Y_1=N=Y_2$. This is the simplest example, but there are many less degenerate examples. Perhaps you wanted independent copies of $N$ as well?

Comment: Dear, what means "independent copies of N as well?" The copies $X_{1j}, X_{2j},...$ are independent of $N$.

Comment: As I explained, the variables you asked about are dependent. That would change if you used $N_1$ in the definition of $Y_1$ and $N_2$ in the definition of $Y_2$, where $N_1,N_2$ are independent.

Comment: Ah, ok. I added a update. Thanks!